# What does a and b stand for in the sorting function

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have started learning javascript a few days ago and I have a bad time understand what these lines:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
```

What is `a` and `b` equal to in this function?
Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: `a` and `b` will be assigned elements from the array. In order to sort the array, pairs of elements are compared. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description): *"If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then: [...] "*

Comment: I suggest that you add a `console.log(a, b);` line before `return b-a`. Can you determine where the output values come from?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

The sorting algorithm implement by `sort()` will call the specified function with various combinations of elements from array to determine which element should go first in the order.  The two chosen element for comparison will be `a` and `b`.